# SplitActionToolBar using ToolBar

Tags: android-toolbar, splitactionbar

I'm trying to create splitActionBar (I think I got the name right) using a regular old Toolbar placed on the bottom.  If you take a look at this post ([How to center action menu on toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26627612/how-to-center-action-menu-on-toolbar)), I am trying to do what the "Answer" says using the Github link, but I don't know how to go about adding a view and using the needed ViewGroup.LayoutParams.

Could someone help me out please?

Here is my relevant code:
           toolbarBottom = activateBottomToolbar();

```
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    toolbarBottom.addView(findViewById(R.id.picture), params);
    toolbarBottom.addView(findViewById(R.id.video), params);

    toolbarBottom.setEnabled(false);

    if (toolbarBottom != null) {
        EnhancedMenuInflater.inflate(getMenuInflater(), toolbarBottom.getMenu(), true);
        toolbarBottom.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                return onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        });
    }
```

The second answer on this post ([Evenly spaced menu items on Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489079/evenly-spaced-menu-items-on-toolbar?rq=1)) also deals with the exact same code that I am dealing with...but again I don't really know how to pass a ViewGroup.LayoutParam.

Comment: Hi, is this problem solved?

Comment: If not, visit please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546160/how-to-enable-split-action-bar/34546493#34546493